# In Xcode, do I enter the version number of my app under build or version

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I am trying to figure out what the version number is compared to the build.  Should there be anything gin the Version field.  4.2 is the current version of my app, should that be under build or version.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version is intended for the User, the build for the Developer. You want to change the version like 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0, but you usually can increment the build like 1,2,3,4...123,124...

Answer (score 0):

Version numbers are the ones displayed in the appstore, and a difference in these will promt the user to upgrade through the appstore.

But during approval, your first build might be rejected, then it's a good idea to indicate that your second build has another build number, to keep them seperated.